# How to access POST data in PHP?

Tags: php, http, post

I need to write a PHP page which would accept an XML document sent over a POST request like this:

```
POST /mypage.php HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: ...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
 ...
</data>
```

This is not data from some HTML form, just a plain XML document.

How can I access this XML in my PHP code?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Read from [`php://input`](http://php.net/wrappers.php). For example, you could use:

```
$rawdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

or

```
$rootNode = simplexml_load_file('php://input');
```

The alternative, using [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php), works, too - but it's slower and needs the PHP configuration [`always_populate_raw_post_data`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data).

Comment: you could also do simplexml_load_file("php://input");

Comment: tomhaigh: Yes, I instinctively avoid that function due to remembering it uses its own subsystem. Turns out, this is not the case anymore as of php 5.1.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` variable](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) or the [`php://input` stream](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Answer (score 2):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA should be available assuming the content-type of the request was not multipart/form-data

Answer (score 1):

[$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)

or

[php://input](http://www.php.net/wrappers.php)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the [PHP input](https://www.php.net/wrappers.php).  Something like

```
$postText = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of these would work:

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA variable or the php://input stream.
```

However, for the

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA variable
```

to work, you might need to change .ini setting in your configuration file

Answer (score -2):

If you use print_r($_POST); you will be able to see what you got. Unless i'm missing something...
Edit: nvm, totaly forgot about Raw Data :/

Comment: $_POST only contains form data, this won't be form data as it has no variable names associated with it.  If for example you post a SOAP packet to a web service, the HTTP Post payload will simply contain XML without any variables attached.