# passing an array data through ajax and POST in php

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

I need to pass array data through ajax, and also should post back it in another page.
but my code is not working, this is my code:

```
var data = [page_num: page, lstGend: <?php echo $gender;?>, lstFrom: <?php echo $fromyear;?>, lstTo: <?php echo $toyear;?>];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "data.php",
    data:{ activitiesArray : data },
    success: function(res) {
        $("#result").append(res);
        console.log(res);
        }
});
```

POST the array:

```
$myArray = $_REQUEST['activitiesArray'];
foreach($myArray as $a){
    echo $a['page_num'];
    echo $a['lstGend'];
    echo $a['lstFrom'];
    echo $a['lstTo'];
}
```

Please help me guys, thnx

[Send JSON data from Javascript to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599595/send-json-data-from-javascript-to-php)

Above issue is not same as mine, i need to pass multiple data(array data), please consider about this.

Comment: Do you have an error code or some output that we can work with?

Comment: I don't understand... What's the point of printing the data with PHP and then using AJAX? Why no use AJAX altogether?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send JSON data from Javascript to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599595/send-json-data-from-javascript-to-php)

Comment: Steven:- no errors! display nothing.

Comment: elclanrs:- actualy im not printing it in my code, i need those 4 variables. here im just trying to show u guys that i need those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace**

```
data:{ activitiesArray : data },
```

**with**

```
data:{ page_num: page, 
       lstGend: <?php echo $gender;?>,
       lstFrom: <?php echo $fromyear;?>,
       lstTo: <?php echo $toyear;?> },
```

and in PHP code make below changes.

**Replace**

```
$myArray = $_REQUEST['activitiesArray'];
foreach($myArray as $a){
    echo $a['page_num'];
    echo $a['lstGend'];
    echo $a['lstFrom'];
    echo $a['lstTo'];
}
```

**with**

```
echo $_POST['page_num'];
echo $_POST['lstGend'];
echo $_POST['lstFrom'];
echo $_POST['lstTo'];
```

Comment: @user2319101 does jQuery added in page.?? does code is wrapped inside `document.ready` for `jQuery.ajax()`

Comment: yep jQuery included. code wrapped inside $(window).scroll(function () {//my code});