# Store javaScript variable value in PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

How can we have JavaScript variable value in PHP variable within the same page??

I have a JavaScript variable which have the JSON String and I want to store in PHP variable so that I can store it into database.
Is it possible??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: you cannot ...but you can do the vice versa

Comment: what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You should write a `php` page accepting the `JSON` using `post` and save it to database.

In javascript when you are ready to save the `JSON`, send the `JSON` to the `PHP` page using `AJAX`. This is the way to save some client side data without using forms.

As explained in this answer

[Send JSON data from Javascript to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599595/send-json-data-from-javascript-to-php)

or if its a form you can refer this answer to submit the serialised data with HTML form

[How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.

$.get('file.php?var='+variable);

Then in PHP $_GET['var'];