# Sending object as param with Javascript xhr

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an array that has a structure similar to the following:

```
var data = [
    {
        'name': 'Foo'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Bar'
    }
]
```

And I want to pass it to my php script with pure Javascript without relying on jQuery.

So my jQuery version would be:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': '/script.php',
    'method': 'POST',
    'data': {'inscriptions': data},
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success': function(response){
        // my code for handling the response
    }
});
```

And in Javascript I have the following:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/script.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
xhr.send(data);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event){

    if(event.target.readyState != XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
        return;

    // my code for handling the response

};
```

However the issue I'm having is that sending it this way in Javascript, my `$_POST` on the server side is empty because the

```
array(0){}
```

And if I change it to:

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({'inscriptions': data}));
```

Then on my server side my `$_POST` will be:

```
array (size=1)
    '{"inscriptions":' => 
        array (size=1)
            '{"name":"Foo"},{"name":"Bar"}' => string '' (length=0)
```

When I send it via jQuery I get the following:

```
array (size=1)
  'inscriptions' =>
    array (size=2)
      0 =>
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'Foo' (length=3)
      1 =>
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'Bar' (length=3)
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing with pure Javascript?

My questions has been marked as a duplicate of [Send JSON data from Javascript to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599595/send-json-data-from-javascript-to-php) but the answer doesn't answer my question. They are using a way to 'bypass' it with:

```
php://input
```

However, it's not sending it directly to the `$_POST` like jQuery does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send JSON data from Javascript to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599595/send-json-data-from-javascript-to-php)

Answer (score -1):

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({'inscriptions': data}));
```