# How to store javascript array or JSON into php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a javaScript array which I need to store in PHP so that later I can store it to MySQL database.

index.php

```
<form method="post">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="php-submit" name="php-submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span></button>
<table class="table" id="table-1">
  <-- my finalArray gets generated by selecting some of these table cell values -->
</table>
</form>
```

app.js

```
$('#php-submit').click(function()
{   // For demo purpose, I have written hardcoded array values here
    var finalArray = ["Nov 2017 0:00 - 0:59", "Dec 2017 0:00 - 0:59", "Nov 2017 1:00 - 1:59", "Dec 2017 1:00 - 1:59"];
    // console.log(finalArray);
    str_json = JSON.stringify(finalArray);
    console.log(str_json);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "script.php",
      data: {data : str_json}, 
      cache: false,
      success: function(){
        alert("OK");
      }
    });

    // $.post('script.php', { data: finalArray }, function (data) { 
    //  alert("OK");
    // });

});
```

After user clicks ('#php-submit') button, 
I want to be display 'finalArray' or 'str_json' on my script.php.

Below are 4 different approaches that I have tried.

script.php

```
// approach 1: output --> blank page

   $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
   foreach($data as $d){
      echo $d;
   }

// approach 2: ouptut --> null

   $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
   var_dump($data);

// approach 3: output --> null

   header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
   $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $json_decode = json_decode($json, true); 
   $json_encode = json_encode($json_decode);
   echo $json_encode;

// approach 4: output --> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "null" }

   $data = $_POST['data'];
   $json_encode = json_encode($data);
   $ar = explode(',', $json_encode);
   var_dump($ar);
```

Comment: This link explains a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599595/send-json-data-from-javascript-to-php

Comment: Try `data: str_json` in your `$.ajax()` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are sending `$.ajax` request but are checking the `script.php` from browser tab. to see your `ajax` request you need to use `Chrome Dev Tools`. Like:

1. Open Chrom Dev Tools with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
2. Move to `Network` Tab. [image]
3. Look for your request in the `XHR` section:[image]

Now I ran your code and it worked just fine for me. As you can see from the screenshots too.

**Edit:** Instead of sending an `ajax` request try submitting a dynaimcally generated `<form>`, Like:

```
$('#php-submit').click(function()
{
    var finalArray = ["Nov 2017 0:00 - 0:59", "Dec 2017 0:00 - 0:59", "Nov 2017 1:00 - 1:59", "Dec 2017 1:00 - 1:59"];
    str_json = JSON.stringify(finalArray);

        var newForm = $('<form>', {
            'action': 'script.php',
            'target': '_top',
            'method': 'POST'
        }).append($('<input>', {
            'name': 'data',
            'value': str_json,
            'type': 'hidden'
        }));
        $(document.body).append(newForm);
        newForm.submit();

});
```

But if you don't want to redirect to another page using `<form>`.Then in your `script.php`, do something like this using [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php):

```
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
    $_SESSION['data'] = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
}

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not change app.js!
Then, you must type this code in script.php:

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['data']);
//To array iteration elements
foreach ($array as $element){
   echo $element;
}
```

Hope It helps you!