# How to send data before recibe it with json_decode?

Tags: php, json, forms

If I have a form in a view to submit a field "id" and the following code in "file.php" to receive it, how should I encode and send it?

"file.php"

```
$body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
echo $body['id'];
```

"in the view"

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="id" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should probably use something like JavaScript to prevent the normal form submission, then use AJAX to send the data by serializing the form. etc.,

Comment: Why does JSON need to be involved? Why not just submit the form and get the id from `$_POST['id']`?

Comment: i get the $_POST['id'] example but i am trying to understand how the encode/decode works.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense. These posts may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599595/send-json-data-from-javascript-to-php, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery

Comment: thanks for the help, this one helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599595/send-json-data-from-javascript-to-php

Answer (score 0):

Based on you PHP code, the JSON string that are going to be received is like this

```
{"id": 123}
```

So, you can encode it like this:

```
$arr['id'] = 123;
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

or like this:

```
$arr = array("id" => 123);
$json = json_encode($arr);
```