# How to use a parameter from a console.log in php

Tags: javascript, json

I am recieving an authorization call back as follows:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("button.authorize").on('click', function(){
        Klarna.Payments.authorize({
            payment_method_category: ''
             
             }, function(res) {
                console.log("Response from the authorize call:")
                console.log(res)
                            })
    })
  })
   
</script>
```

Which returns:

```
Object { show_form: true, approved: true, finalize_required: false, authorization_token: "mytoken" }
```

How can I use the value of authorization_token in the following url:

```
https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/authorizations/**res.authorization_token**/order
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send JSON data from Javascript to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599595/send-json-data-from-javascript-to-php)

Comment: `res.authorization_token`?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I did the following: https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/authorizations/res.authorization_token?/order but that did come up with forbidden any idea how to use the res.authorization_token?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure what this question has to do with [tag:php].

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation or template strings:

- Concatenation: `var s = 'https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/authorizations/' + res.authorization_token + '/order';`
- Template strings: `` var s = `https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/authorizations/${res.authorization_token}/order`; ``

(Another method which I wouldn't recommend is joining an array to build the final string: `var s = ['https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/authorizations', res.authorization_token, 'order'].join('/');`. Nothing to gain by this, but I've added it for completeness' sake)

But it's probably a good idea to do a tutorial on the basics of JavaScript before integrating a third-party payment API. So much that can go wrong and money is involved.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however when I use res.authorization_token in the url ot return a bad authorization token is there a way I can check that the console.log(res) is getting the token? Print it out somehow? I am very sorry but I just am very stuck

Comment: @Ria I'm not sure I understood your question. `console.log` will print any string (or object) that you pass to it.

Comment: I am so sorry, I cannot get the results to display/use on my page I would like to print the authorization token on my page so it would say something like "mytoken" as a result

Comment: And cross fingers that `res.authorization_token` isn’t `../../../delete-all-my-stuff`

Comment: @Ria "print on my page" does that mean adding it to the DOM or logging it with `console.log`? Note that "how to add something to the DOM" is a very different question from "how to use a JSON property in my request's URL". If you have a second question, please post a new one.