# Capture data sent by curl -d with PHP

Tags: php, curl, capture

I'm trying to capture data sent by curl using PHP but it doesn't appear on my end.

I'm executing via console:

```
curl -d "tests_123" "http://www.example.com/capture.php"
```

and I have in capture.php

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

But nothing appears.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Answered fully in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664148/how-to-access-post-data-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sure that you can get the data with `$response = file_get_contents('php://input');`

However, If you change your command a little bit, and add a key to the value you are sending, you can get the data from your $_POST variable quite easily.

```
curl -d "Mykey=tests_123" "http://www.example.com/capture.php"

print_r($_POST);
// array ( Mykey => test_123)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this to capture such data:

```
$log.="http_get_request_body \n";
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$log.=print_r($entityBody,true);
$log.="\n----------------\n\n";
```

Thanks to @crodas for this! :)